# On Change, Fileupload jQuery event doesn't work with upload from mobile, but does with desktop?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

This jQuery function works when I upload from my desktop computer but doesn't fire when I upload file from mobile phone.  What's the issue?  Here is the event code.

Javascript

```
$('#pet_pic').on('change', function(e){         

    $('#layoutForm').ajaxSubmit(options);           
    // return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
    return false;

});
```

HTML

```
<input id="pet_pic" name="pet_pic" type="file" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to handle mobile related events

```
$("#pet_pic").on("taphold",function(){

});
```

Comment: is this work for desktop version too or just for mobile?

Comment: This will work for mobile only and for desktop version keep you code as it is.